# Как сделать вывод данных из массива?

Tags: php, массивы, php7, ldap

Как вывести данные displayname и l ?

есть массив данных из ldata  [вот сделал вывод массива](http://extremje.bget.ru/lichnyij-kabinet/korzina)

```
$info = ldap_get_entries($adconn, $result);
 print $info["count"]." entries returned";
 foreach($info as $item) {
        echo "<pre>";
         print_r($item);
        echo "</pre>";
 }
```

пробовал так, но не выводит ничего

```
foreach ($info as $item)
    if (is_array($item)) foreach ($item as $v) {
        if (isset($v['displayname']))
            print_r($v['displayname']);
        if (isset($v['l']))
            print_r($v['l']);
    }
```

Comment: а в чем сложность то?

Comment: добавил в вопрос, как пробую, не выводит ничего

Comment: содержимое массива можно в переменной, а не результатом ? Попробую у себя.

Answer (score 0):

решил, сделал вот так

```
$filter = "(cn=*)";
$att = array( "displayname", "l", "accountexpires");
```

и цикл вот такой

```
 foreach ($info as $item){
         if (is_array($item)) {
            echo $item['l'][0];
            echo $item['displayname'][0];
            echo "<br>";
            echo date('d.m.y H:i:s', $item['accountexpires'][0]);
            echo "<br>";
            echo $item['accountexpires'][0];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```

но поле accountexpires - это дата выводится вот так

```
 [accountexpires] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 9223372036854775807
                )
```

при `echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $item['accountexpires'][0]);` выдает `27.01.-292277022657 11:29:51`